# Why did this solve my performance issue?

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, android-relativelayout

I have an android app, with a view where I show a map. This map is built using [this library](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view).

I have just found a fix to the map being laggy (inside a `RelativeLayout` around the map):

```
-    android:background="@drawable/background_flare"
```

Yes, that is a one-line commit to solve a performance issue. The background_flare image is 102KB.

Now my question is why this solved the problem. Is there a known problem with backgrounds on `RelativeLayout`s, or is there a bug with the library so that it takes the image around when you pan the map?

Also worth noting, this bug only shows on a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini (`GT-I9195I`), running Android 4.4.4.

Any ideas?

Comment: How your `background_flare` looks like? It might be that it is a big image -> it takes quite a lot of time to load this as a texture on GPU -> drawing is slow.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev It's `414 × 736`

Comment: where is your background_flare i mean location, some times android may take time to resize the image at runtime

Comment: @Sree It is inside my shared drawable folder (it's a Xamarin cross-platform project)

Comment: ok try with a small resolution image if it worked then it may be a rendering problem

Comment: @vrwim it is quite big image, therefore you have rendering problems. You can try to replace `RelativeLayout` with any other layout and you'll see the same problem. It does not matter how good compression of your image is, 1000x1000 RGBA8888 image which weights 10Kb would draw as fast as 1000x1000 RGBA8888 image which weights 10000Kb.